# Insertar cadena usando regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex

Estoy buscando en internet pero no encuentro ninguna solución valida, ni siquiera parecida, a lo mucho uno que otro ejemplo que ya incluye una coma `(,)` de por medio, lo cual hace la labor un poco más fácil, pero ese no es mi caso... Lo que quiero saber es ¿como puedo agregar una coma de por medio entre las **palabras y números** con **expresiones regulares** en **Python 3**? Pensé en separar haciendo distinción entre **mayúsculas, minúsculas y números** pero la verdad no sé como entrarle a ese problema ya que no manejo expresiones regulares... apenas estoy incursionando en ello.

Por ejemplo tengo esta cadena:

> UlrikGreenshore580 gpKrooxKazordoon580 gpCedrikLiberty Bay580 gpBrengusPort Hope580 gp

Y quisiera separarla de esta forma:

> Ulrik,Greenshore,580 gp,Kroox,Kazordoon,580 gp,Cedrik,Liberty Bay,580 gp,Brengus,Port Hope,580 gp

Al final la idea es rebanar usando la coma `(,)` (o cualquier otro signo de puntuación que sirva de referencia) para crear una lista de elementos... pero de eso yo me puedo encargar.

P.D.: No dejo código ya que me quedé atascado en ese `string` que obtengo como resultado de la ejecución de mi programa. **Específicamente el uso de expresiones regulares** para este problema me dará solución a otros inconvenientes que tengo en otros programillas y será tanto un excelente modo de practicar como de incursionar en el mundo de las Regex.

Saludos y gracias desde ya!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías separar la cadena sin recurrir previamente a regex o usar directamente `re.split`, pero contentando a tu pregunta con respecto a insertar la coma, en principio puedes usar una expresión como:

```
((?<!^)(([A-Z]+[a-z]*(\s+[A-Z])?[a-z]*))|(\d+(\s+[a-zA-Z]?[a-z]*)))
```

- **`()`** -> Grupo de captura.
- **`(?<!^)`** -> look behind, se asegura que lo que sigue no esté al inicio de la cadena (`^`).
- **`([A-Z]+[a-z]*(\s+[A-Z])?[a-z]*)`**: primera posibilidad, palabra

  - **`[A-Z]`** -> clase de caracteres, letras mayúsculas.
  - `**+`** -> Cuantificador, uno o más, voraz, tantas veces como pueda.
  - **`[a-z]`** -> clase de caracteres, letras minúsculas.
  - **`*`** -> Cuantificador, 0 o más, voraz, tantas veces como pueda.
  - **`\s`** -> literal para el espacio.
  - **`?`** -> Cuantificador, cero o una vez.
- **`|`** -> `or`
- **`(\d+(\s+[a-zA-Z]?[a-z]*)`**: segunda posibilidad, número

  - `\d` -> Clase de caracteres, dígitos del cero al 9.

---

```
import re


patt = re.compile(
    r'((?<!^)(([A-Z]+[a-z]*(\s+[A-Z])?[a-z]*))|(\d+(\s+[a-zA-Z]?[a-z]*)))'
    )

cad = "UlrikGreenshore580 gpKrooxKazordoon580 gpCedrikLiberty Bay580 gpBrengusPort Hope580 gp"
res = patt.sub(r",\1",  cad)
```

> ```
> >>> res
> 'Ulrik,Greenshore,580 gp,Kroox,Kazordoon,580 gp,Cedrik,Liberty Bay,580 gp,Brengus,Port Hope,580 gp'
> ```

En `r",\1"`, `\1` se refiere al primer grupo de captura.

La expresión está escrita sobre la marcha y sin un testeo adecuado, es muy posible que pueda ser simplificada o que pudiera fallar en ciertos escenarios no contemplados en el ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

dejo lo que logré:

```
import re

str1 = 'UlrikGreenshore580 gpKrooxKazordoon580 gpCedrikLiberty Bay580 gpBrengusPort Hope580 gp'

print(re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', str1))
```

El de los números está difícil, lo que haría sería aplicar una expresión regular sobre el resultado de la primera.